# return from http get request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm trying to make an API call but it keeps saying that curr_price (what I'm returning) is undefined? I think it might have something to do with the asynchronous nature of javascript but I'm not sure? Any help would be appreciated!!

```
function getPrice(today, callback){
    var url;
    var username = 'some username';
    var password = 'some password'; 
    url = 'some url'+ createTimeString(today);

    var options = {
        host: 'some host',
        path: url,
        auth: username + ':' + password
    };

    https.get(options, function(res){
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(d) {
            body += d;
            var obj = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(obj);
            callback(obj.Entries[0].EntryPx);
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            //console.log(body);
        });

        res.on('error', function(e) {
                context.fail("Got error: " + e.message);
        });         
    });
}

getPrice(today, function(result) {
    curr_price = result;
    speechOutput = "The curr price is " + curr_price.toString();

    //rest of code
});
```

Comment: what is context.fail?

Comment: Have you tried to move `var obj = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(obj);
            callback(obj.Entries[0].EntryPx);` to `res.on("end", ...)`

Comment: Return from HTTPRequest, where to?

Comment: https.get?  Are you using node,js?

Comment: `console.log(obj)` please show the output of this and also log `d`, i.e., data you get in `on.('data'..` method

Answer (score 0):

I would say you guessed right, I am not completely sure, but this might have to do with asynchronous nature. I am assuming that's the case because I think you have already checked the object and its properties to see that it actually isn't `undefined`. The AJAX call you make takes time, however the lines of code after ajax call get executed immediately after and do not wait for http response, that's why you get `undefined`.

One way you can fix this by moving the call to `getPrice()` inside `res.on('data', ...)`.
More generally, you need to do everything you want with the http response inside the response handler function itself.

You can refer to [this video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/html-css-javascript-for-web-developers/lecture/25hv4/lesson-57-part-3-ajax-basics) for better understanding. The video showcases a very similar issue to the one you have.